# How to implement authentication based on organization

Tags: authentication, clojure

I'm building a web app using Clojure and ClojureScript and I need it to have authentication based on a white-list of organization. For example, let's say I've added University1.edu to my white-list, and when a student from that university wants to login to my web app, they would be redirected to their own universities login system. After that I would just a confirmation of whether or not they successfully logged in there and maybe create a session, cookies, or or something for them.

Is that possible and if so, how can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some common ways to implement this authentication schemes are [OAuth2](https://stfalcon.com/en/blog/post/oauth-2.0) and [OpenID](http://openidexplained.com/), which are commonly used in websites were you can log in with your social / Twitter / Facebook / Google account.

Using OAuth for instance, you register your website in some developer portal (depending on the service that you'll use to authenticate) and obtain a token that that you'll use during the login flow and after logging on their portal, users are redirected back to your site.

In order for this to work, every organization (eg. University1) needs to be a provider of this authentication scheme, so that's something you'll need to research.

In Clojure there is a couple of options: the [buddy](https://github.com/funcool/buddy) library seems to be a popular choice, but you could also use some [Java libraries](https://oauth.net/code/java/) through interop.

Comment: Denis than you for your answer, that helps!